# Android Capture Screen to Surface of ImageReader

Tags: android

I am currently learning code of one github project ScreenCapture, which can capture the screen and show the image in a surfaceview, here is the project https://github.com/Charlesjean/android-ScreenCapture. I tried to replace the surface of SurfaceView with surface of a ImageReader Object with the code below:

```
 mImgReader = ImageReader.newInstance(mWidth, mHeight, ImageFormat.JPEG, 5);
    mSurface = mImgReader.getSurface();// mSurfaceView.getHolder().getSurface();
    mImgReader.setOnImageAvailableListener(new ImageReader.OnImageAvailableListener() {
        @Override
        public void onImageAvailable(ImageReader reader) {
            Log.i(TAG, "in OnImageAvailable");

        }
    }, mHandler);
```

and create VirtualDisplay like this:

```
mVirtualDisplay = mMediaProjection.createVirtualDisplay("ScreenCapture",
              mWidth, mHeight, mScreenDensity,
              DisplayManager.VIRTUAL_DISPLAY_FLAG_OWN_CONTENT_ONLY |
                      DisplayManager.VIRTUAL_DISPLAY_FLAG_PUBLIC,
              mSurface, new VirtualDisplay.Callback() {
                  @Override
                  public void onResumed() {
                      Log.i(TAG, "onResumed");
                      super.onResumed();
                  }

                  @Override
                  public void onPaused() {
                      Log.i(TAG, "onPaused");
                      super.onPaused();
                  }
              }, mHandler);
```

but the `onImageAvailable` method is never called, does anyone have any experience on this? I could not figure out why this does not work.

Comment: Did you check logcat? It might be an image format issue. Try `PixelFormat.RGBA_8888` isntead of `ImageFormat.JPEG`.

Comment: @SimonMarquis I will try and give you feedback.

Comment: @Charlesjean Your project link is not working. I need some reference to your project . Can you share

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Thanks Simon, I solved the problem by change image format to PixelFormat.RGBA_8888, but there is some other points you need to take care when you are doing what I did, I post it here in case it will help someone in the future.

The data buffer of `Image.Plane` is not exactly the same as data buffer needed by `Bitmap`:
 1. The image format we used to create `ImageReader` is PixelFormat.RGBA_8888, so the buffer of Image.Plane will place R(ed) channel at first, and then G(reen) channel and so on. In order to convert this buffer to bitmap, we need to create bitmap like this 
`bitmap = Bitmap.createBitmap(metrics,width, height, Bitmap.Config.ARGB_8888);`
 and the buffer of bitmap need to put Alpha channel at the first.
2. The buffer we got from `Image.Plane` have some padding for each row, personally I think this is used by hardware device to accelerate buffer operation or for alignment. So in order to copy this buffer, we need to drop these padding.

To understand the two points, please see the code blow:

```
 public void onImageAvailable(ImageReader reader) {
            Log.i(TAG, "in OnImageAvailable");
            FileOutputStream fos = null;
            Bitmap bitmap = null;
            Image img = null;
            try {
                img = reader.acquireLatestImage();
                if (img != null) {
                    Image.Plane[] planes = img.getPlanes();
                    if (planes[0].getBuffer() == null) {
                        return;
                    }
                    int width = img.getWidth();
                    int height = img.getHeight();
                    int pixelStride = planes[0].getPixelStride();
                    int rowStride = planes[0].getRowStride();
                    int rowPadding = rowStride - pixelStride * width;
                    byte[] newData = new byte[width * height * 4];

                    int offset = 0;
                    bitmap = Bitmap.createBitmap(metrics,width, height, Bitmap.Config.ARGB_8888);
                    ByteBuffer buffer = planes[0].getBuffer();
                    for (int i = 0; i < height; ++i) {
                        for (int j = 0; j < width; ++j) {
                            int pixel = 0;
                            pixel |= (buffer.get(offset) & 0xff) << 16;     // R
                            pixel |= (buffer.get(offset + 1) & 0xff) << 8;  // G
                            pixel |= (buffer.get(offset + 2) & 0xff);       // B
                            pixel |= (buffer.get(offset + 3) & 0xff) << 24; // A
                            bitmap.setPixel(j, i, pixel);
                            offset += pixelStride;
                        }
                        offset += rowPadding;
                    }
                    String name = "/myscreen" + count + ".png";
                    count++;
                    File file = new File(Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory(), name);
                    fos = new FileOutputStream(file);
                    bitmap.compress(Bitmap.CompressFormat.JPEG, 100, fos);
                    Log.i(TAG, "image saved in" + Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory() + name);
                    img.close();
                }

            } catch (Exception e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            } finally {
                if (null != fos) {
                    try {
                        fos.close();
                    } catch (IOException e) {
                        e.printStackTrace();
                    }
                }
                if (null != bitmap) {
                    bitmap.recycle();
                }
                if (null != img) {
                    img.close();
                }

            }
        }
```

Comment: Were you able to capture screen outside the app?

Comment: You might think that this Bitmap would be the proper size. However, it is not. For inexplicable reasons, it will be a bit larger, with excess unused pixels on each row on the end. This is why we need to use Bitmap.createBitmap() to create a cropped edition of the original Bitmap, for our actual desired width.

We then compress() the cropped Bitmap into a PNG file, get the byte array of pixel data from the compressed result, and hand that off to the ProjectorService via updateImage(), Thanks to https://commonsware.com/Android/previews/screenshots-and-screen-recordings

Comment: Did you try updating your opengl viewport to not use padding?

That is a feature with a control somewhere, but I can't remember the exact option.

Comment: If you are using opengl, this is how to tell it to not add padding to your bytes:

        GLES20.glPixelStorei(GLES20.GL_UNPACK_ALIGNMENT, 1);
        GLES20.glPixelStorei(GLES20.GL_PACK_ALIGNMENT, 1);

Answer (score -2):

```
private void createCameraPreviewSession() {
    mPreviewRequestBuilder.addTarget(mImageReader.getSurface());
    mCameraDevice.createCaptureSession(Arrays.asList(surface,mImageReader.getSurface()),
    new CameraCaptureSession.StateCallback() {}
}
```